# How to enable NTLM auth in Tor Browser on Windows?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, authentication

How I can enable NTLM auth in Tor Browser on Windows? I tried to change `network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1` to true, but it not works. 
I need to authenticate on IIS 8.5 server that require NTLM authentication, but when I try to make it server return 401 error even without credentials promt.
It works on Firefox so I believe that its a Tor Browser specific bug.
I will be very appreciate for help.

Comment: The point of Tor is anonymity. SSO seems like a great way to lose that. NTLMv1 in particular is broken and probably also blocked at the OS layer. Settings and info here https://markgamache.blogspot.com/2013/01/ntlm-challenge-response-is-100-broken.html

Answer (score 1):

NTLM is disabled by intent, apparently due to an embargoed Mozilla bug (I.E. the details aren't public), this is done through patching. The change is hardcoded into the browser so editing preferences won't make any difference. It's applied through [this patch](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/commit/?h=tor-browser-45.6.0esr-6.5-1&id=4425a1ba1e06ea905b8c102d239b861a3a9b06f1).

The associated ticket for the patch can be found here: [#12974](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12974).

*(My suspicion is that this can lead to a local credential leak and so could seriously harm user anonymity)*